# Minimize is returning unevaluated for a simple positive integer domain problem

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I don't understand why the following `Minimize` code is returning unevaluated.  I believe I have it coded  properly and the expected minimum is $x=14$ and $y=1$.

```
 Minimize[{1 + x == 15 y, x >= 14 y}, {x, y}, PositiveIntegers]
 (* Minimize[{1 + x == 15 y, x >= 14 y}, {x, y}, PositiveIntegers] *)
```

Can `Minimize` not solve this problem?

Comment: What does this give you: `Minimize[{1 + x = 15 y, x >= 14 y}, {x, y}, PositiveIntegers]` ??

Comment: @Syed  That syntax returns a "Tag 1+x is protected" message but does return the minimum.   The double equal sign however is the standard syntax for an equation and I would prefer adhering to strict syntax and not encountering unnecessary messages or errors with my code.  Thanks though.

Comment: What are you trying to minimize? You only supply two conditions, but no function that shall be minimized. `Solve[{1 + x == 15 y, x >= 14 y}, {x, y}, PositiveIntegers]` works fine.

Comment: @Roman:  In the case above, there are other values which satisfy the relations such as $(29,2)$, $(46,3)$ and so on.   I am looking for the smallest.  This concerns a larger problem of $x+a==ny$  with a set of inequalities $x+a_j>=iy$  with $a,b,a_j,n$ all positive integers.  Above is only a simple example and I have some concern  or skepticism `Solve` would not always give me the smallest.

Comment: The "smallest" by what metric?  For example, is (29, 2) "smaller than", "bigger than", or "equal to" (28,3) under the ranking you have in mind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify what you mean by "smallest solution". If it means that you want the smallest value of $x+y$, then you can do

```
Minimize[{x + y, 1 + x == 15 y && x >= 14 y}, {x, y}, PositiveIntegers]
(*    {15, {x -> 14, y -> 1}}    *)
```

You can define other quantities to be minimized; but you cannot skip defining what you mean by "smallest".